Why the EOM from the variation of the metric coincide with the EOM from the variation of an ansatz for the metric?
Suppose we have a pure gravitational action $S[g_{\mu\nu}]$ and we obtain, via the usual variation procedure, its associated Equation Of Motion (EOM) for any $g_{\mu\nu}$. After that, we can give an ansatz for $g_{\mu\nu}$ and solve the EOM.
Reversing the argument, we can set the ansatz to $g_{\mu\nu}$ before the general variation procedure. This is, substitute the components of $g_{\mu\nu}$ and its associated curvature tensors in $S[g_{\mu\nu}]$ and then vary this action with respect to the components.
Why do both procedures give the same EOM in the most common cases (black hole, FRW, ...)? Is there any case where the result is not the same? They sould be always the same? What's the reason, if it only works for few symmetric cases, why it works?
Example:
The Einstein-Hilbert action is given by
\begin{equation}
S[g_{\mu\nu}] = \dfrac{1}{16\pi G}\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \; R \; ,
\end{equation}
after varying this action with respect $\delta g_{\mu\nu}$ we obtain (ignoring boundary terms and so on) the Einstein equations
\begin{equation}
G_{\mu\nu} = R_{\mu\nu} -\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R = 0 \; (\text{or $=8\pi G T_{\mu\nu}$ if we consider matter}) .
\end{equation}
Now suppose we want to solve this for the Schwarzschild metric (FRW metric can be another example), we just set $g_{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(-A(r),B(r),r^2,r^2\sin^2(\theta))$ in the Einstein equations and obtain the associated EOM1 for $A$ and $B$.
Instead, we can calculate the metric determinant $\sqrt{-g}$ and Ricci scalar $R$ for the Schwarzschild metric and substitute the expression in the Einstein-Hilbert action $S[g_{\mu\nu}]$. Now $S[g_{\mu\nu}]$ will depend on $A$, $B$ and their derivatives, so we can obtain their associated EOM2 using the Euler-Lagrange equations (possibly in their higher-derivative generalization if it is needed).
I've done the calculation and EOM1 = EOM2, they are the same equations. Both methods provide the same equations of motion (the same is true for the FRW metric case with a lapse function), what is the reason behind it? It is always the case? Only in highly symmetric metrics? Why?

Both procedures do NOT give the same equations, unless your metric ansatz is of a special form, e.g., obtained by some symmetry ansatz.

@Prahar Can you develop more about what role plays the symmetry here? Is there any heuristic argument?

Suppose you have an action $S[g]$ and you have a ansatz that sets a particular component of the metric to zero, say $g_{12}=0$ (for example). Let us consider the two methods you described:
1. First vary, then substitute the ansatz
In this case, you vary $S[g]$ w.r.t. all metric components first and obtain some set of equations ${\cal E}^{\mu\nu} = 0$. You will now substitute the ansatz here and solve ALL the equations. In particular, you must also  solve ${\cal E}^{12} = 0$, which is the equation corresponding to the variation of $S$ w.r.t. $g_{12}$.
2. First substitute the ansatz, then vary
In this case, your action $S[g]$ no longer contains $g_{12}$. Consequently, when you vary this new action, you will miss out on the equation ${\cal E}^{12} = 0$. Your new set of equations of motion will NOT be the same as the old set as you are clearly missing out on (at least) one equation.
Q. Why does OP always get $EOM_1=EOM_2$?
The only way it is possible to ensure that the two sets of equations are identical is if it so happens that ${\cal E}^{12}$ identically vanishes when you set $g_{12} =0$ irrespective of what all the other metric components are. This is what happens in all the cases that OP has considered.
More generally, the statement is that you are allowed to set a field $\phi$ to zero in the action if and only if the following holds identically
$$
\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi} \bigg|_{\phi=0} = 0. \tag{1}
$$
Q. How can I ensure (1) will hold a priori?
One way to guarantee that (1) will hold is to write down the most general ansatz (the most general part is important) consistent with some symmetry of the theory. Since both the action and EOM are invariant under the symmetry (by definition), any ansatz that is consistent with symmetry will necessarily respect (1).

Thanks for your answer!

The solutions of the first method are necessarily solutions of the second method. Indeed, in the first method, the solutions are stationary with respect to a wide range of variations, instead of just the ansatz variations in the second method (which form a subset).
You can build intuition in finite dimension. Let $g\in\mathcal G$ be in a finite dimension space (analogue of a specific field in the set of all possible field configurations) and $S(g)$ a real function (analogue of the action). Choosing an ansatz is restricting your attention to a subset $G\subset\mathcal G$. Stationary points of $S$ in $G$ are stationary points of $S$ restricted to $G$ by the same reasoning. In general though, the equation you will obtain will be different, since the second method will typically include more solutions.
Take for example $\mathcal G = \mathbb R^2$ and $G = \{(x,ax)|x\in\mathbb R\}$ and $S(x,y) = \cos(x)+\cos(y)$. The "EoM's" for the first method are:
$$
\sin x = \sin y = 0
$$
so when restricting to the ansatz:
$$
\sin x = \sin (ax)= 0 \tag{EoM1}
$$
Therefore, you have no solutions when $a$ is irrational. However, for the second method:
$$
S(x) = \cos x+\cos(ax)
$$
so the new "EoM" is:
$$
\sin x+a\sin(ax) = 0 \tag{EoM2}
$$
The equations are different and since EoM1$\implies$EoM2 you have more solutions. You can now understand where these extra solutions come from, there are other solutions outside your ansatz space and the second method tries to "mimic" them within the ansatz space the best it can. This is a generic phenomenon common to all variational principles (maximum entropy, mean field etc.). These extra solutions may be desirable if you trust your ansatz subspace to be sufficiently close to these outside solutions.
Actually, it is a bit surprising that you got rigorously the same equations. I did not do the calculations myself, but I would expect that you could get EoM2 from EoM1 by differentiating or multiplying by extra factors (at least some level of mathematical cosmetics).
